# Does adding a disconnect box below the meter mean that my service panel is now a subpanel?

Tags: electrical, wiring, grounding-and-bonding

I don't understand the bonding at my main disconnect. My problem is that my main panel in the house was wired OK with the neutral bonded to ground. The power company added a disconnect box below the meter box.  I noticed the disconnect they installed doesn't have the neutral bonded to ground. Am I going to have a problem? From what I read my main panel is now a sub panel because they added a disconnect? I am wondering why they thought it was OK.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: What is your location?

Answer (score 2):

If the power company did not change the bonding point, you still have a main panel ("the one with the bond in it.")

So long as **there's only one**, the location of the bond can and does vary with the preferences of the power company, mostly. Mine is inside the meter box, so my panel **is** wired as a sub-panel.

On a typical panel run from a meter and bonded in the panel, the meter itself is a disconnect point that's upstream of the bond, and that's not a problem.

You should realize that the neutral and ground conductors are not interrupted by a disconnect, so the bond in your panel is still effective even with a disconnect upstream of it.

If the power company had opted to move the bond point, they would have needed to rewire your panel - a considerable expense (for them) and inconvenience (for you) they avoid by not changing the bond point.